# Images are not getting saved to database after .NET 6 upgrade

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-5

Recently we've upgraded our ASP.NET 5 Web API to .NET 6 along with all nuget packages and everything worked fine until we noticed that new images are no longer saved to our MySQL database.

Any images that are under 40kb seems to be saving perfectly fine still, but as soon as they go over that size they fail to save. There are no errors being thrown, and no logs that indicate that anything went wrong.

When we checked the DB the mediumblob is not null, as we would expect, but rather a empty blob. Telling me that 'something' was saved.

My gut is telling me that after handing the `byte[]` to Entity Framework that something happened during the conversion. Possibly something to do with serialization. I'm aware that .NET 6 has a new `System.Test.Json` converter, but we're not utilizing this, we're using Newtonsoft.

Things I've tried:

- Remove Newtonsoft and use `System.Text.Json` instead, unfortunately this wasn't straight forward and caused a ton of other issues
- Installed Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql instead of the MySQL.EntityFrameworkCore, but this cause issues with the existing `DbContext`.
- Using a breakpoint just before the `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` is called, shows me that the `byte[]` is still populated, and nothing wrong there. But after the `SaveChanges`, the blob in the database is empty. All other changes to DB saved correctly.
- I reverted back to .net 5 and previous package versions and can confirm that all images are saving 100% correctly. Then I only changed the .NET 5.0 to .NET 6.0 in the project file, and can confirm this is what causes this issue.

I'm not sure code wise what I can show here.

Does anyone know of anything that changed on .NET 6 that would create an issue like this?

The documentation didn't have any breaking changes listed, and we had to upgrade since .NET 5 is no longer supported.

Startup.cs

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 64;
            });
```

`CampaignService.cs`:

```
campaignToUpdate.CampaignName = campaign.CampaignName;
campaignToUpdate.CampaignDescription = campaign.CampaignDescription;
campaignToUpdate.StartDate = campaign.StartDate;
campaignToUpdate.EndDate = campaign.EndDate;
campaignToUpdate.PrizeDescription = campaign.PrizeDescription;

campaignToUpdate.PrizeImage = campaign.PrizeImage;

campaignToUpdate.IsIndividualCampaign = campaign.IsIndividualCampaign;
campaignToUpdate.IsTeamCampaign = campaign.IsTeamCampaign;

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`DbContext.cs`:

```
entity.Property(e => e.PrizeImage).HasColumnType("mediumblob");
```

Edit 1:

As soon as I update these two Nuget packages in a new application, then I get the same error:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore V 6.0.15
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore V 6.0.10

Not sure if this might be related, but our MySQL Server is still running on V5.7

Edit 2:

Installed MySQL 8.0.27 on my local and still getting the same result.

Edit 3 Code:

`UpdateCampaignImageRequest`:

```
public class UpdateCampaignImageRequest
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

`TestController.cs`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromBody] UpdateCampaignImageRequest request)
    {
        await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        var campaign = await _dbContext.Campaigns.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CampaignId == request.CampaignId);

        if (campaign == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        campaign.PrizeImage = request.Image;

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await _dbContext.Database.CommitTransactionAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

`Campaign.cs`:

```
public class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int? ChallengeId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
    public string CampaignDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string PrizeDescription { get; set; }
    public byte[] PrizeImage { get; set; }
    public string PrizeImageName { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCampaignCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsIndividualCampaign { get; set; }
    public bool IsTeamCampaign { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? TotalParticipants { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CurrentLeader { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasInviteEmailSent { get; set; }
}
```

`Context.cs`:

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
    }

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Campaign>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CompanyId, "Campaigns_ibfk_1");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ChallengeId, "Campaigns_ibfk_2_idx");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.StartDate, e.EndDate }, "StartDate");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UniqueCampaignCode, "UniqueCampaignCode")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.CampaignId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CampaignDescription).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.CampaignName).HasMaxLength(30);

            entity.Property(e => e.ChallengeId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PrizeDescription).HasMaxLength(500);

            entity.Property(e => e.PrizeImage).HasColumnType("mediumblob");

            entity.Property(e => e.PrizeImageName).HasMaxLength(64);

            entity.Property(e => e.UniqueCampaignCode)
                .HasMaxLength(6)
                .IsFixedLength(true);
        });
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Using:

- .net6.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore V6.0.15
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore V6.0.10
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore V6.0.15
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection V6.0.1

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro and test if this issue is specific to MySql?  If your entity has data in a `byte[]` property, there's no JSON serialization between there and the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I managed to replicate the issue in a new application.

As soon as I update these two Nuget packages, then I get the same error:
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore V 6.0.15
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore V 6.0.10

Comment: I did fail to mention that we're still running MySQL 5.7.
I'm not sure if the new MySQL EntityFramework is only compatible with MySQL 8.x

Comment: Installed MySQL 8.0.27 on my local and still getting the same result.

Comment: Can you use a db profiler to capture the db interaction? Then you can see what is actually being sent and executed in MySql. If you do that for both versions (working / not working) you can compare the difference and hopefully that will lead you to what the underlying problem is.

Comment: There are no real changes in that respect between .NET 5 and 6, and STJ is nothing new. It was introduced in .NET Core 3. That's why you're using `AddNewtonsoftJson`. Not that it has anything to do with EF Core and database access.

Comment: EF Core won't hide errors either, it will throw an exception if the operation fails. What does `CampaignService.cs` really do? How is this code called? Are exceptions logged or hidden with a `catch{}` ? Can you post an actual *minimal* example that fails? `CREATE TABLE` schema, and a minimal Console example that tries to save a single image and fails. You don't need an actual image either, just a bunch of random bytes.

Comment: As for Pomelo - fix the problems with the existing DbContext and use it. Oracle's package is so buggy it's essentially useless. Pomelo is *more* popular than Oracle's package and far faster to fix problems. Pomelo fixes problems that Oracle's package had for several years.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've actually created a new API and managed to replicate the issue with minimal code. All it does is update the image in the Table.

Comment: Post the code in the question so *we* can replicate it. And use Pomelo. I can't stress how bad Oracle's driver is - there's no point trying to troubleshoot it. You can't fix its bugs and Oracle may take years to fix them. Pomelo uses a real open-source MySql provider instead, that fixes Oracle's bugs. Just [look at the list of fixed bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/). Some of the bugs fixed in Pomelo's MySqlConnector are open for years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually installed Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql in the new test application and it is working. Unfortunately it doesn't work with our 2-3 year old API. Getting a lot of threading errors around the DBContext.

Comment: And 5 of the fixed issues are for BLOBs

Comment: That means your API is broken. DbContext isn't thread-safe nor meant to be - it's a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It doesn't even keep an open connection until it persists all changes in a single transaction when you call `SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: If you use the same DbContext across threads you have far bigger problems that are probably causing the problems. This has nothing to do with any EF Core changes. One of Oracle's bugs is that it didn't have real asynchronous operations until recently. The code you assumed was asynchronous was *blocking* in reality, which is the only way you didn't get threading errors earlier

Comment: It's quite possible that now that your Oracle driver no longer blocks, this is the first time your code is  trying to use DbContext concurrently and fails as expected

Comment: I've edited the post with the code to replicate the issue using the MySQL package.

I'm actually quite surprised that the official MySQL package is so broken, that it actually 'accepts' the not thread-safe context as is.
Thank you for the insight.

We will need to do a in-depth analysis of where what is going wrong and then potentially do a refactor.

Comment: But I'm guessing for the interim that there's no workaround for the MySQL blob issue?